# How to addObject as NSMutableArray in NSMutableArray in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I want to `addObject` of `NSMutableArray` into `NSMutableArray` so how can I achieve this in swift.
and also retrieve it so please help me because right now I'm learning swift.

Indirectly say that I want 2D array means `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArray`.

```
//The below 2 lines iterative!
var dict:NSMutableDictionary? = NSMutableDictionary();
 linePointsArray!.addObject(dict!);

// and below 2 line is execute after complete the above iteration
 arrLine!.addObject(linePointsArray!);
 linePointArray!.removeAllObject();

//after that the above whole process is done iterative.
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If I am not wrong you want to add an object of NSMutableArray in another NSMutableArray you can do it by following code

```
var myArray : NSMutableArray = ["Hello"]
var arrayOfArray : NSMutableArray = [myArray]

// Insert more arrays with insertObject or addObject

arrayOfArray.insertObject(myArray, atIndex: 0)
arrayOfArray.addObject(myArray)

//Retrive
var newArray:NSMutableArray = arrayOfArray[0] as NSMutableArray
println("\(newArray)")
```

**For Swift 3:**

```
var myArray : NSMutableArray = ["Hello"]
var arrayOfArray : NSMutableArray = [myArray]

// Insert more arrays with insertObject or addObject

arrayOfArray.insert(myArray, at: 0)
arrayOfArray.add(myArray)

//Retrive
var newArray:NSMutableArray = arrayOfArray[0] as! NSMutableArray
print("\(newArray)")
```

Comment: my newArray returns with 0 count

Comment: in my newArray there is a collection of NSMutableDictionary but it returns count 0

Comment: means myArray has objects of dictionary, but newArray returns count 0

Comment: or else modify your question with the code so that we can play that in playground

Comment: now also i solve my problem with nil the array instead of remove all object (but why this happen that i don't know  this code is propare work in objective c)

Comment: How to add custom object to array

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example:

```
var mutableArray: NSMutableArray = []
var nestedMutableArray: NSMutableArray = []
mutableArray.addObject(nestedMutableArray)
var retrievedNestedMutableArray:NSMutableArray = mutableArray[0] as NSMutableArray
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nameArray: NSMutableArray = ["Hello", "I", "am", "Smith"]
var arrayOfnameArray: NSMutableArray = [nameArray]

arrayOfArray.add(nameArray)

// Retrieve
var newArray:NSMutableArray = arrayOfnameArray[0] as! NSMutableArray
print("\(newArray)")
```

Comment: Code answers are generally not accepted without an explanation of what this code actually achieves. So you'll need to add a bit more explanation on how this code can help people can solve their problem.